# Verb agreement with some subjects

Tags: verb-agreement

Are the following sentences correct?

> It's high time the government took steps to eradicate terrorism.
>
> It's high time to take steps to eradicate terrorism.

I am asking this question because I have learned that the verb should be in the past form if we use "high time".

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything wrong with *"it's high time the government takes steps to eradicate terrorism"*? It's the indicative and not the mandative subjunctive, which changes the meaning from something that isn't likely to happen to something that is likely to happen, but I believe it's still grammatical.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 3):

*High time* is an idiom which is almost always used in that sentence frame (*It's high time X did Y*).

Using it outside that frame is grammatical, as Barrie says, but I'd go further than him and describe it as very unusual.

The word *time*, without the *high*, may take either frame:

> It's time the government took steps.
>
> It's time to take steps.

or even, as Peter Shor suggests

> It's time the government takes steps.

though I think that option is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically possible, but the first construction is probably more usual.